# How to make ListView show all my images?

Tags: android, eclipse, image, listview

I'm new at developing and I started making an app to show a list of 30 images, but somehow, it only shows the first 10 images. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong. If you could help me, I will be much appreciated.

This is a part of what I have:

```
int[] vehs = new int[]{
    R.drawable.veh1,
    R.drawable.veh2,
    R.drawable.veh3,
    R.drawable.veh4,
    R.drawable.veh5,
    R.drawable.veh6,
    R.drawable.veh7,
    R.drawable.veh8,
    R.drawable.veh9,
    R.drawable.veh10,
    R.drawable.veh11,
    R.drawable.veh12,
    R.drawable.veh13,
    R.drawable.veh14,
    R.drawable.veh15,
    R.drawable.veh16,
    R.drawable.veh17,
    R.drawable.veh18,
    R.drawable.veh19,
    R.drawable.veh20,
    R.drawable.veh21,
    R.drawable.veh22,
    R.drawable.veh23,
    R.drawable.veh24,
    R.drawable.veh25,
    R.drawable.veh26,
    R.drawable.veh27,
    R.drawable.veh28,
    R.drawable.veh29,
    R.drawable.veh30
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    List<HashMap<String,String>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put("veh", Integer.toString(vehs[i]) );
        aList.add(hm);
    }

    // Keys used in Hashmap
    String[] from = { "veh" };

    // Ids of views in listview_layout
    int[] to = { R.id.veh };

    // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
    // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item
    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), aList, R.layout.listview_layout, from, to);

    // Getting a reference to listview of activity_main.xml layout file
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // Setting the adapter to the listView
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

It only shows from veh1 to veh10 :(

Comment: `for(int i=0;i<10;i++){` maybe changing the top index?

Comment: create an array of your images then call the function that creates an image into the loop

Comment: @nKn I already tried to change i<30, for example, and I still got the same thing. Only shows first 10 images. Do you know how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like maybe it's having trouble mapping the strings to drawables.

try this to map the resources as int's instead of strings.

```
List<HashMap<String,Object>> aList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();

for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
    HashMap<String, Object> hm = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    hm.put("veh", Integer.valueOf(vehs[i]) );
    aList.add(hm);
}
```

Comment: I added this, but it still shows the first 10 images :/

Answer (score 0):

I dont have much experience with `SimpleAdapter` , i've always been creating my own custom adapter mostly extending `BaseAdapter`. If I were you i'd create my own adapter to handle that problem . Check out the code below it should work like a charm.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

Context context;
int[] vehList;

public CustomAdapter(int[] vehList, Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.vehList = vehList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return vehList.size();
}

@Override
public int getItem(int position) {
    return vehList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if( convertView == null ){
        //We must create a View:
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context)
                  .inflate(R.layout.YourListViewLayoutRow, parent,false);
    }

   // this is where you create each row . Get current item from vehList
   int currentItem = vehList.get(position);
   // and then assigne the values and return the view object 
    return convertView;
}
```

}

Then the activity code:

```
int[] vehs = new int[]{
    R.drawable.veh1,
    R.drawable.veh2,
    R.drawable.veh3,
    R.drawable.veh4,
    R.drawable.veh5,
    R.drawable.veh6,
    R.drawable.veh7,
    R.drawable.veh8,
    R.drawable.veh9,
    R.drawable.veh10,
    R.drawable.veh11,
    R.drawable.veh12,
    R.drawable.veh13,
    R.drawable.veh14,
    R.drawable.veh15,
    R.drawable.veh16,
    R.drawable.veh17,
    R.drawable.veh18,
    R.drawable.veh19,
    R.drawable.veh20,
    R.drawable.veh21,
    R.drawable.veh22,
    R.drawable.veh23,
    R.drawable.veh24,
    R.drawable.veh25,
    R.drawable.veh26,
    R.drawable.veh27,
    R.drawable.veh28,
    R.drawable.veh29,
    R.drawable.veh30
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(getBaseContext() , vehs);

    // Getting a reference to listview of activity_main.xml layout file
    ListView listView = ( ListView ) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

ListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```